# MOTD Advertisement for CS:GO Server

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, hosting, server-administration

I have sprung up a 66TICK CS:GO server via hosting (Provider being `Hypanova`) and have successfully edited the `...\csgo\motd.txt` file to look something like so:

> //MOTD points to server
>
> http://blahaddress.bladdomain.blah

This should now show whenever someone joins my server (or so I believe). I have not tested this yet as I am working on the website (trying to make it steam browser friendly).

I now want to add in random chat messages like

`Server 1: Welcome %playername% to %server%. The current level is %serverlevel%`

I can get the syntax right when I find the file. What is the best method to perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that there is a nice plugin - [Advertisement 0.6](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?p=592536) that performs what I need to an extent. This solves my question.

Should anyone feel I need to provide a more through answer let me know and I will revise.